# Explaining a Function inside a Function in R

Tags: r, function

I got confused when I stumbled upon this code as you don't need to give "y" a value to operate, how does it get its value?

```
f <- function(x) {
    g <- function(y) {
            y + z
    }
    z <- 4
    x + g(x)}
```

because if I add ran this code

```
z <- 10
f(3)
```

it will give the result (10), where the second function got its "y" value?

Comment: It is in the signature for `g()`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel can you explain more?

Comment: `x + g(x)` compute the sum of `x` and the result of calling `g()`.  The definition of `g()` shows that the argument is called `y` there.  So `3 + g(3)` becomes `3 + (3 + 4)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call function g() inside f(), you passed "y" value by using g(x). Whatever value you assigned to x will be assigned to y inside function g().
So the result is x+g(x)=x+x+z=3+3+4=10

Comment: Thanks for re-writing what I wrote half an hour earlier as essentially the same in a comment <wink>